# setLayoutFrozen(boolean) and setHasFixedSize(boolean) purpose for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am wondering what are those two methods doing? I have tried to set it on my RecyclerView but it doesnt seems to do anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

`setLayoutFrozen(true)` prevents any updates to the UI such as changing images and even pauses events on the Layout such as scrolling. This also stops childviews from being updated as well.

When events are stopped, they are not queued and will be dropped. It basically stops everything including adapters and return events like view state. Something that could be useful if you have multiple views layered and want to make sure the user and any data updates cannot affect that area, say like in a folded back/partially visible view behind a popped-up icon.

`setLayoutFrozen(false)`can essentially be thought of as an onResume() for RecyclerViews once called after the freeze.

`hasFixedSize()` is a return value, so not something you can set. It returns true only if the adapter will not change the size of the RecyclerView, even if the adapter has new content. i.e. a Fixed size screen Card-type view that doesn't allow scrolling

**[REFERENCE HERE IN ANDROID API DOCS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setLayoutFrozen(boolean))**